# WPF Datagrid cell coloring

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How we add color for a cell programmatically in WPF Data grid?I can add color to row wise,but i want to add color to cell from the code behind side.Please provide code for that?

Answer (score 4):

What this code do: At first, you handle the `LoadingRow` event, get the row (it has the Item property which holds your bound item), get the bound item, make all needed calculations, get the cell you need to alter and finally alter the style of the target cell.

Here is the code (as item I use a sample object with the int `ID` property that I use for coloring).:

**C#:**

```
private void FillTheDataGrid()
{
    List<SomeClass> list = new List<SomeClass>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {        
       list.Add(new SomeClass() { DaysOld = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(rnd.Next(5), 0, 0, 0)), ID=i});
     }
     dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
}

private void dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => AlterRow(e)));
}

private void AlterRow(DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = GetCell(dataGrid, e.Row, 1);
    if (cell == null) return;

    var item = e.Row.Item as SomeClass;
    if (item == null) return;

    var value = item.ID;

    if (value <= 1) cell.Background = Brushes.Red;
    else if (value <= 2) cell.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
    else cell.Background = Brushes.Green;
}

public static DataGridRow GetRow(DataGrid grid, int index)
{
    var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as DataGridRow;

    if (row == null)
    {
        // may be virtualized, bring into view and try again
        grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
        row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    }
    return row;
}

public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        var v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T ?? GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}

public static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid host, DataGridRow row, int columnIndex)
{
    if (row == null) return null;

    var presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
    if (presenter == null) return null;

    // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
    var cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex);
    if (cell == null)
    {
        // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
        host.ScrollIntoView(row, host.Columns[columnIndex]);
        cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DaysOld { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow"/>
```

Comment: @RintoAntony If my reply helps to you, it is possible to mark it as an answer to simplify search for other people.

Comment: Excellent! Couple of imhos: 1) without column virtualization it looks like branch with ScrollIntoView is not necessary, 2) in real life usually there are more columns, and since we're processing the whole row, it does not make sense to repeat GetVisualChild for each cell in the row - it will be the same.

Comment: @sarh feel free to add your edited answer!:) Please, notify me of you publish new answer! I will upvote for the answer.

Comment: thanks, but I think it will be unfair. Your answer has everything which is needed to make it work, I've just shared couple of optimization thoughts, I even not sure it will be significantly faster. And I persanolly don't like when after my answer I see another one almost the same just with some bells and whistles.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, finally i found the answer and it is easier than what i was thinking, here is the code to change the cell color porgramatically:

```
DataGridRow firstRow = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataGrid.Items[i]) as DataGridRow; 
firstColumnInFirstRow = dataGrid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(firstRow).Parent as DataGridCell;
firstColumnInFirstRow.Background = Brushes.IndianRed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whats in your DataGridCell you can create a DataTemplate which binds to the color or used a trigger

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cell:MyCellObject}"> 
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Text}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MyBackground}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />

                <Style.Triggers>    
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBool}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkRed" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>

           </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```